# python unicode errors convert to printed values

Tags: python, unicode

If I have some unicode like this:

```
'\x00B\x007\x003\x007\x00-\x002\x00,\x001\x00P\x00W\x000\x000\x009\x00,\x00N\x00O\x00N\x00E\x00,\x00C\x00,\x005\x00,\x00J\x00,\x00J\x00,\x002\x009\x00,\x00G\x00A\x00R\x00Y\x00,\x00 \x00W\x00I\x00L\x00L\x00I\x00A\x00M\x00S\x00,\x00 \x00P\x00A\x00R\x00E\x00N\x00T\x00I\x00,\x00 \x00F\x00I\x00N\x00N\x00E\x00Y\x00 \x00&\x00 \x00L\x00E\x00W\x00I\x00S\x00,\x00U\x00S\x00,\x001\x00\r\x00'
```

and it's read in from a csv in string format, but I'd like to convert it to a human readable form.  It works when I print it, but I can't seem to figure out the approach command to make save it to a variable in human readable form.  What is the best approach?

Comment: You have a string of bytes

Comment: did you try `print(x.encode('utf8'))`

Comment: ya print will work, i want the printed text to be saved to a variable

Comment: @Rob : variable = x.encode('utf-8') ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have Unicode. Not *yet*. You have a series of bytes, and those bytes use the UTF-16 *encoding*. You need to decode those bytes first:

```
data.decode('utf-16-be')
```

Printing it works only because your console ignores most of the big-endian pair of each UTF-16 codeunit.

Your data is missing a [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), so I had use the `utf-16-be`, or *big endian* variant of UTF-16, on the assumption that you cut the data at the right byte. It could also be *little* endian if you didn't.

As it is I had to remove the last `\x00` null byte to make it decode; you pasted an odd, rather than an even number of bytes, as you cut one UTF-16 code unit (each 2 bytes) in half:

```
>>> s = '\x00B\x007\x003\x007\x00-\x002\x00,\x001\x00P\x00W\x000\x000\x009\x00,\x00N\x00O\x00N\x00E\x00,\x00C\x00,\x005\x00,\x00J\x00,\x00J\x00,\x002\x009\x00,\x00G\x00A\x00R\x00Y\x00,\x00 \x00W\x00I\x00L\x00L\x00I\x00A\x00M\x00S\x00,\x00 \x00P\x00A\x00R\x00E\x00N\x00T\x00I\x00,\x00 \x00F\x00I\x00N\x00N\x00E\x00Y\x00 \x00&\x00 \x00L\x00E\x00W\x00I\x00S\x00,\x00U\x00S\x00,\x001\x00\r\x00'
>>> s[:-1].decode('utf-16-be')
u'B737-2,1PW009,NONE,C,5,J,J,29,GARY, WILLIAMS, PARENTI, FINNEY & LEWIS,US,1\r'
```

The file you read this from *probably* contains the BOM as the first two bytes. If so, just tell whatever you use to read this data to use `utf-16` as the codec, and it'll figure out the right variant from those first bytes.

If you are using Python 2 you'd want to study the [*Examples* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) of the `csv` module for code that can re-code your data in a form suitable for that module; if you include the `UnicodeReader` from that section you'd use it like this:

```
with open(yourdatafile) as inputfile:
    reader = UnicodeReader(inputfile, encoding='utf-16')
    for row in reader:
        # row is now a list with unicode strings
```

Demo:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> import codecs
>>> f = StringIO(codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE + s[:-1])
>>> r = UnicodeReader(f, encoding='utf-16')
>>> next(r)
[u'B737-2', u'1PW009', u'NONE', u'C', u'5', u'J', u'J', u'29', u'GARY', u' WILLIAMS', u' PARENTI', u' FINNEY & LEWIS', u'US', u'1']
```

If you are using Python 3, simply set the `encoding` parameter to the `open()` function to `utf-16` and use the `csv` module as-is.